# set UIMenuController on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller

My `UIView` is inside `NSObject class` and I want to show `UIMenuController` on this view.

But app is crashing with error

> cannot become first responder

Answer (score 2):

Only Inherits From UIResponse can become first responder, so if you want a view to show a MenuViewController, maybe your view must do this:

`-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
   return YES;
}`